# Cannot get _id of MongoDB object with java driver

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm inserting objects into MongoDB without specifying the _ids, because I want it to create them automatically. The problem is that at a certain point of the program I need to retrieve the _ids, but I can't get them. The code I use is the following:

```
List<DBObject> objs=collection.find(filter).toArray();
BDObject obj=objs.get(0);
String id=obj.get("_id");
//now id is something like 2d938830-2732-44fd-84b0-aa56b95c5df0
```

Eventually the id variable contains a GUID, but it's different from the one I see in RoboMongo, so it's wrong. What I see in RoboMongo is something like:

```
"_id": LUUID("cada0d4f-a72d-47ad-8ea8-239c3e5795dd")
```

Comment: Mongo java driver performs serialization/deserialization for you. Can you add the POJO used to store the documents?

Comment: There is no POJO because it's a test application. It creates the objects with a GUI. The program just tells where to click. It's selenium...

Comment: Can you add the code that inserts objects into mongo? Maybe the code sets `uuid` before inserting?

Comment: I don't have that code

Comment: You don't actually show the query conditions you are supplying, so there is no actual "guarantee" you are actually returning the same document. You need to show the conditions you are applying in both your code and the other source so we can see that they should in fact return the same document. The actual internal type here is `Binary`, and it has a consistent subtype so it does not "change the value". You simply have different documents.

Comment: but it only has one document